# How can I handle a custom child event, emitted via this.$emit, in a parent component, within the <script> portion of the .vue file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

We are using vue and typescript, so our .vue files are organized essentially identically to [this blogpost.](https://alligator.io/vuejs/typescript-class-components/)

I have a child component emitting the custom event `changeType`. I would like to invoke a function on the parent component upon this event being emitted.

**childComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span @click="changeType('test')"></span>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class ChildComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop(
    {
      default: 'notTest',
      validator: (type) => {
        return [
          'test',
          'notTest',
        ].indexOf(type) > -1;
      },
    },
  )
  currentType!: string;

  changeType(currentType = 'notTest') {
    this.$emit('changeType', currentType);
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, I'm unsure what to put in my **parentComponent.vue** file, which has `<childComponent />` in its `template` area.

The [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events) only addresses the handling of child events within the `<template>` area of a file, using `v-on`:

```
<blog-post
  ...
  v-on:enlarge-text="postFontSize += 0.1"
></blog-post>
```

So, I suppose, do I need to have something like:

**parentComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <childComponent v-on:changeType="handleChangeType" />
</template>
```

Or is there some way to do it in the `<script>` tag area only? Research has been made more difficult by the use of the class + typescript syntax. I was having some goes at things like `this.$on` but typescript did not like that at all, or perhaps I was putting it in the wrong section of the class (perhaps it belongs in the constructor or similar?)

I come from a Backbone background, so I was hoping for something like a `onChangeType` method added directly to the parent component would automatically handle the event, though perhaps that is old school and there's newer better ways.

**How can I handle a child component event within the  tags of a parent component in vue?** Is it possible without `v-on` within the template? Am I misunderstanding the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an event listener to a child component via the [`$on` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on), which you mentioned.

First, you'll need to add a `ref` to the child component in the template:

```
<childComponent ref="child"/>
```

Then, in the `mounted` hook, you'll add your listener like so:

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.child.$on('changeType', this.handleChangeType);
}
```